# Printing an struct that includes an 2d array

Tags: c++, struct, multidimensional-array

EDITED
What I am trying to do is (after reading from file and putting the information in 2d array defined in a struct,that part works) call a method that finds out if there is any zeroes in the array and if so change it and prints it again. I know I´m missing pointers but I don't know where. Thanks in advance.

```
struct matrix{
const static int N=9;
int Ar[N][N];
};

void iprint(matrix s){ //my method to print the array
    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            cout << (s).Ar[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

bool annotation(matrix s, int row, int column, int num){
    if(s.Ar[row][column] == 0){
        (s).Ar[row][column] = num;
        return true;
    }
    else if(s.Ar[row][column] != 0){
        cout << "NO" << endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        cout << "No" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    iprint(s);
}
```

The array in first place :

```
0 0 6 5 0 0 1 0 0
4 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 9
0 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 8
0 7 0 1 0 0 5 0 0
0 8 0 0 0 0 0 6 0
0 0 3 0 9 0 0 4 0
2 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 0
9 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 3
0 0 5 0 0 8 2 0 0
```

The output that I get after those methods (calling the method   `annotation(s,1,1,2);` )

```
2686428 0 0 2686524 8989288 4733208 0 0 -17974607
1 0 4201360 4662484 0 8989288 8989340 9005760 0
.
.
.
```

Im reading the array from a file,and the method is

```
bool readMatrix(matrix s){
ifstream f;
f.open("nuMatrix.txt");
if (f.is_open()) {
    while(!f.eof()){
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
            f>>(s).Ar[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    f.close();
    iprint(s);
    return true;
}
else {
    cerr << "NO";
    return false;
}
```

}`

Comment: How do you read the array in, in the first place?

Comment: What is the use of *iprint(s)* when you have return in every if and else

Comment: What *should* the output be?

Comment: the output should be the same array but changed s.Ar[1][1]=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix you're passing to `readMatrix` and `annotation` isn't modified by the functions.
You're passing the matrix by value, so you're only modifying a copy of it.

Change your functions to take a *reference* to a `matrix`:

```
bool annotation(matrix& s, int row, int column, int num)
bool readMatrix(matrix& s)
```